# LeftCurly on the same line except for comments in checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'd like my left curly braces to be on the same line as the end of the declaration including exceptions in general, i.e.

```
void someMethod () throws Exception {
```

or

```
void someMethod ()
throws Exception {
```

instead of

```
void someMethod () throws Exception
{
```

However, if I want to comment the exception outside of Javadoc, the brace needs to be moved to the next line in order to assure that it's no commented out and that it doesn't appear after the brace which would make it harder to associate with the exception, so I need checkstyle to recognize this one special case or a hint what I'm not seeing, e.g.

```
void someMethod() throws Exception
    //that's ugly, fix later. The reason Exception is thrown is because of this
    //very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
    //very very very very very very very very very very long reason that spans
    //multiple lines
{
```

The comment outside Javadoc might be an addition to a `@throws` explanation, e.g. something the caller shouldn't be bothered with. There're few use cases for this since it's recommended to share as much in the visible Javadoc, but I also want to broaden my understanding of checkstyle.

Comment: If this is a valid workaround: I prefer putting comments on stuff before the respective stuff, as it is done in java source code. See for example [String.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) (lines 241, 248, ...).

Comment: I see. It's easy to associate those comments with the statements on the following lines and it'd look weird to place them after the statements, while it's much clearer in the case above to put the comment after the argument or exception. There seem to be no such comments in String.java; on line 2462 and others they do it the way I want to avoid because it's not as clear as possible where the comment belongs to especially if there's more than one thing to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would consider placing the comment about the exception directly under it - after the left curly brace:

```
void someMethod()
        throws Exception {
    // todo: that's ugly, fix later. The reason Exception is thrown is
    // because of this very very very very very very very very very very
    // very very very very very very very very very very very very very
    // very very long reason that spans multiple lines.
```

You can also reconsider placing it in the Javadoc, or are you really determined not to put it there?

Yet another option is to suppress the Checkstyle warning in this exceptional situation with the `SuppressWarnings` annotation (defined in `java.lang`):

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:leftcurly")
void someMethod()
        throws Exception
    // todo: that's ugly, fix later. The reason Exception is thrown is
    // because of this very very very very very very very very very very
    // very very very very very very very very very very very very very
    // very very long reason that spans multiple lines.
{
```